# how to add text to h2 tags and recognize embedded tags like < i >

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variable `event.link` that I am passing here from DB: `$('#someh2tag').text(event.link);` 
The issue is that `event.link` has italic styling already and sometimes returns strings like:
"Grammar: Subjects Pronouns: < i >We, You, They< / i >" instead of making text italic.
How can I pick up on those tags and actually make it recognize it?
Thanks

Comment: Use `html()`, not `text()`. I'd suggest you have a cursory glance through all the methods jQuery exposes. They're all pretty self explanatory and give you a good idea of what's possible: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: Thank you! Changing to html worked.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Please consider adding your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `text()` method HTML encodes the string before you append it.

To fix this, use `html()` instead:

```
$('#someh2tag').html(event.link);
```